# Visual Studio Team Services build error cannot copy AssemblyAttributes.cs

Tags: azure, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

After adding a web role to my Azure project I get a build error within my Visual Studio Team Services environment. Though, I cannot figure out what is causing this. Where is AssemblyAttributes.cs comming from? I cannot find this file in my solution folder.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.7\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets (2787, 5)
Unable to copy file "C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs" to "C:\a\6e05cef4\xxxx\xxxx.Backend.Api.Azure\obj\Debug\Tijdmunt.Ui.WebRole\C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs". The given path's format is not supported.
```

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio Online?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed in visual studio online.

Comment: I am having the same issue did you ever figure this out?:

Comment: Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

*AssemblyAttributes.cs* is a temporary generated file created by MSBuild, so It's not going to be on your solution. Instead it is going to be under the temporary folder.

Since It's a temporary file and created on every build, I just went to below location and deleted the file, then my solution started to be successfully building again.

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs

Hope this helps someone else.